# Issue while Configuring parallel Z3 using z3 <smt2-file > CC_NUM_THREADS=3

Tags: python, z3, z3py, sat

Issue while Configuring parallel Z3  using z3  CC_NUM_THREADS=3

I am trying to run z3 parallel version with  CC_NUM_THREADS=3 for my smt2 file
the following error is poping up.

```
ERROR: unknown parameter 'cc_num_threads'
Legal parameters are:
 auto_config (bool) (default: true)
 debug_ref_count (bool) (default: false)
 dump_models (bool) (default: false)
 memory_high_watermark (unsigned int) (default: 0)
 memory_max_alloc_count (unsigned int) (default: 0)
 memory_max_size (unsigned int) (default: 0)
 model (bool) (default: true)
 model_validate (bool) (default: false)
 proof (bool) (default: false)
 rlimit (unsigned int) (default: 4294967295)
 smtlib2_compliant (bool) (default: false)
 timeout (unsigned int) (default: 4294967295)
 trace (bool) (default: false)
 trace_file_name (string) (default: z3.log)
 type_check (bool) (default: true)
 unsat_core (bool) (default: false)
 verbose (unsigned int) (default: 0)
 warning (bool) (default: true)
 well_sorted_check (bool) (default: false)
```

Answer (score 0):

This feature is not supported anymore (and hasn't been for a long time). You can craft your own parallel tactics, see, e.g., the par-or example in the Tactics section of the [Strategies Tutorial](http://rise4fun.com/Z3/tutorial/strategies).